# Finding if the set contains its supremum

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on a problem and I am having an issue deciding whether or not the set contains its supremum. I am asked to give an example of two sets that are disjoint, have the same supremum, and neither set contains its supremum. I have come up with the following sets:

Let $X=\{r\in\mathbb{Q} : r^2 <2\}$ and $Y=\{r\not\in\mathbb{Q} : r^2 <2\}$.

Comment: There isn't anything special about $\sqrt{2}$ here. You could also consider something like $(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ and $(0,1)\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Another example: Every other term of a strictly increasing bounded sequence (e.g., $\{1- \frac1{2n}:n\in\mathbb N\}$ and $\{1-\frac1{2n+1}:n\in\mathbb N\}$).

Comment: @MPW Understood, thank you! Then is my set choice okay?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course, it's true because $(\sqrt2)^2<2$ is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

$\sup(X) = \sup(Y) = \sqrt{2}$ because the rationals and the irrationals are both dense.

$\sqrt{2} \notin X$ as $X$ only contains rational numbers, and $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational, and $\sqrt{2} \notin Y$, as it does not obey the defining condition of having a square *strictly* less than $2$.